# Название всех таблиц в базе. Sql-запрос (ms sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как с помощью sql-запроса, можно получить название всех таблиц в конкретной базе данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

или

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type='U'
```